# Can't add layers to new PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, qgis-3

I made a new PostgreSQL database and am trying to add layers/tables to it in QGIS using the DBManager. And I am failing.

Here is the error message I'm getting:
[image]

However, I can add layers to other PostgreSQL databases that previously existed. I thought it might be some problem in the way I created the new database, using pgAdmin 4, but as far as I can tell the new database is exactly the same as the others.

I tried some workarounds, including creating a new schema in an existing database and couldn't read from that new schema.

Any suggestions?

Comment: which data format are using to upload the data?

Comment: Maybe PostGIS extension is not installed in this database. If not, try CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis; What does this command say?: SELECT PostGIS_full_version();

Comment: *If* you created a template database for PostGIS, then you could specify it in the database creation command. Please remember to include the text of the error message in the body of the Question; this makes the error legible on all devices and searchable as well.